# Discord bot line of code not working, in an if statement

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so I've been stuck on this for a couple days now, and I can't seem to figure it out. The program is supposed to send characters on an adventure, and when typing a non existing character the bot recognizes that, but when typing an existing character the bot just does not respond back.

```
  for i, slot in enumerate(adventure_slots):
    if not slot:
      adventure_slots[i] = True
      break
  else:
    return

  await ctx.send(f"{character_name} has been sent on an adventure! They will return in 3 hours.")
  await asyncio.sleep(3 * 3600)  # 3 hours in seconds

  await ctx.author.send(f"{character_name}'s adventure is complete! You can collect your loot now.")
  session.close()
```

Comment: Yes, I want it to respond with (f"{character_name} has been sent on an adventure! They will return in 3 hours.")

Answer (score 0):

```
  for i, slot in enumerate(adventure_slots):
    if not slot:
      adventure_slots[i] = True
      break
  else:
    return
```

return leaves the function. I am assuming what you mean is simply:

```
  for i, slot in enumerate(adventure_slots):
    if not slot:
      adventure_slots[i] = True
      break
```